# Power BI, "Group By Columns" property of the TOM is resetting on data refresh

Tags: powerbi, tabular-object-model

I set the "Group By Columns" TOM property in Tabular Editor.  When I refresh the data the property resets to not having the columns grouped.

This is the property I am referring to.
[image]

I'm exploring how Field Parameters are using the Group By Columns property to match the "*fieldparametername*Fields" to the "*fieldparametername*Fields Fields" columns to create a Composite Key.  The Group By Columns property in Field Parameters persists after a data refresh.